# Magento 1.9 - Catalog URL Rewrites - Index product and categories URL rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9

Invalid backend model specified: enterprise_catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey

[image]
Please see the image below for error. I am not able to index this field.

Answer (score 0):

You have a module rewriting:

```
 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
```

It Would be:

```
 Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
```

Look for the existence of this model. This is what is preventing the reindex

UPDATE: Enterprise is the module in this case. So this would be in app/code and the model would be app/code/ (either community or local)/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php

if you are using a ide like phpstorm just shift x2 and search for this class name

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please let me know on which file I have to update this.